# Schreibe ich „diejenige“ vor das Substantiv oder dahinter?

Tags: sentence-structure, article

Wie sagt man richtig auf Deutsch?

> Sie ist die Frau, diejenige, die gestern dich angerufen hat.
>
> Sie ist diejenige Frau, die gestern dich angerufen hat.

Oder sind die Sätze beide möglich? Meine Frage betrifft den Demonstrativartikel *diejenige*, wie benutzt man ihn richtig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Strukturen sind *möglich*, allerdings ist in allen Fällen die zweite vorzuziehen.

Im ersten Fall hast du einen Anfangssatz »Sie ist die Frau«. Der *Frau* wird in einer Apposition nachgestellt, welche Frau es ist: »diejenige, die gestern dich angerufen hat.« Und wie alle Appositionen muss auch diese durch paarweise Kommas abgetrennt werden (das zweite Komma entfällt, weil der Satz zuende ist):

> Sie ist die Frau, diejenige, die gestern dich angerufen hat.

Dass er möglich ist, macht den Satz aber noch nicht schön oder sonstwie wohlgeformt. Und ich tue mich schwer, dort »nur« ein Komma zu setzen; ich würde es lieber mit einem Strichpunkt (oder gleich einem Punkt) in zwei Sätze teilen:

> Sie ist die Frau; diejenige, die gestern dich angerufen hat.

Wenn das jemand so sagt, dann weil die Person den Satz angefangen hat, eine kurze Denkpause macht, und dann ab *diejenige* wieder weiterspricht. Geschrieben solltest du ihn nur in direkter (wörtlich wiedergegebener) Rede finden.

---

**Sehr viel besser in jeglicher Hinsicht** ist es, *diejenige* wie einen gewöhnlichen Artikel zu verwenden, also direkt vor das entsprechende Substantiv zu stellen.

> Sie ist diejenige Frau, die gestern dich angerufen hat.

Analog zu:

> Sie ist die Frau, die gestern dich angerufen hat.
>
> Sie ist eine Frau, die gestern dich angerufen hat.
>
> Sie ist jene Frau, die gestern dich angerufen hat. (etwas ungebräuchlicher)

In allen diesen Fällen hast du es nur noch mit einem ganzen Satz zu tun, der aus Haupt- und Nebensatz besteht. Du hast überflüssigen Konstruktionen wie die Apposition im ersten Fall, und es bietet sich nicht an, die beiden Teile stärker als durch ein Komma zu trennen. So könnte man es auch in geschriebenen Texten lesen.

---

**Ein Nachsatz zur Wortreihenfolge:** der Nebensatz ist so definitiv *möglich*, aber ungewöhnlich, weil unnötige Spannung enthalten ist. Besser wäre folgende Satzstellung:

> …, die dich gestern angerufen hat.

Denn *dich* ist kürzer als gestern und im Zweifel (wieder im Gegensatz zu *gestern,* aber auch zu *anrufen*) die bekannte Information.

(Je nachdem, wie der Satz ausgesprochen wird, erfährt entweder *dich* oder *gestern* in deiner Wortstellung eine zusätzliche Betonung. Die neutralere Satzstellung ist die hier im Nachtrag.)

Comment: deine Antwort ist perfekt... ich danke dir ;) :)

Comment: Ich würde bei _die gestern dich angerufen hat_ im Gegenteil das _dich_ als betont ansehen („im Gegensatz zu der, die gestern mich angerufen hat“). Will man _gestern_ kontrastieren, ist das nur über die Betonung möglich: _Die Frau, die dich gestern angerufen hat, nicht die, die dich heute angerufen hat._

Comment: @chirlu Hmm, stimmt; da hat mir wohl die Intonation in meiner inneren Stimme einen Streich gespielt … So oder so stimmst du mir aber sicher zu, dass die Reihenfolge *… dich gestern …* besser ist, ja?

Comment: Ja, das ist sicherlich die neutrale Anordnung.